# Lock down AWS EC2, to the office colleagues

Tags: security

I need some advice. I need to lock down serveral EC2 instances to only colleagues in the office, which is approx 45x users+. We have various office arrived the world.

Security Groups came to mind, as a quick/short term solution. But thinking about it further, i need to consider the colleagues, who travel to different offices or WFH, so entereing a LAN ip address may not work.

Am i am going down the wrong track of thinking of a Customer Gateway/Vitural Priviate Gateway. Does this seem to over board, also possiblly a expensive option in the long run.

Any advice, will be appericated.

Answer (score 0):

You have number of options

1. Setup VPN for all your colleagues and restrict security groups from VPN only
2. Use AWS IAM , AWS Active Directory to restrict logins

Comment: What about taggin the instances, add the approved users to a group in IAM, create a role that allows the approved actions on the instances based on the tag, attach the role to the group.

Comment: Yes, that's an option too.